# Speeding up iterating over a range and comparing a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, comparison, list-comprehension

I have this loop that generates a combination of numbers and solves to see if they equal a solution. After running a profiler I find that the sum and the comparison to the solution take the longest amount of time. Is this just due to the number of calls to each of them or would there be a way to make this faster?

Profiler output:
[Name, Call Count, Time(ms), Own Time(ms)]

[listcomp, 23114767, 5888, 5888] 25% of total time.

[builtin.sums, 23164699, 3097, 3097]  12% of total time

[image: I've attached an image of the profiler]

Right now I can't think of a way to reduce the search range so trying to save time elsewhere :)

Thanks for the help.

```
rangedict = {'f1': range(1850, 1910), 'f2': range(2401, 2482), 'f3': range(5150, 5850)}
coefficient = [-3, 1, 1]
possiblesolution = 1930

for combination in itertools.product(*rangedict.values()):
    if solutionfound:
        break
    else:
        currentsolution = sum([x*y for x, y in zip(coefficient, combination)])
        if currentsolution == possiblesolution:
            solutionfound = True
            dosomething()
```

Comment: a minor speedup: do not create a list in your `sum`; `sum(x*y for x, y in zip(coefficient, combination))` will do.

Comment: `<listcomp>` probably stands for list comprehension and not list comparison, btw.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying. Also changing the sum to not be a list actually slowed it down. That is the sum builtin.sum time. With list:  3182 , without list: 11451 ms

Comment: and you could pack the coeffs into the ranges: `rangedict = {'f1': range(-3*1850, -3*1910, -3), 'f2': range(2401, 2482), 'f3': range(5150, 5850)}` and simplify the sum: `currentsolution = sum(combination)`.

Comment: You don't need the first `if solutionfound`. Move the `break` into the `if currentsolution == possiblesolution:` after `dosomething()` or whatever comes at the end after you find a solution. This way you avoid the unnecessary check that is probably False most of the time.

Comment: Can you post the profiler output as plain text, rather than a tiny image that's virtually unreadable?

Comment: I thought it would be a link and not embed it. Added the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments: packing the coefficients into the `ranges` directly will speed the whole thing up a bit:

```
from itertools import product

possiblesolution = 1930
solutionfound = False
rangedict2 = {'f1': range(-3*1850, -3*1910, -3),
              'f2': range(2401, 2482), 
              'f3': range(5150, 5850)}

for combination in product(*rangedict2.values()):
    if sum(combination) == possiblesolution:
        solutionfound = True
        print(combination[0]//(-3), combination[1], combination[2])
        break
```

---

or a completely different approach: create a dictionary of the sums you can get from `f1` and `f2` and then check if your goal `possiblesolution` can be reached:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rangedict3 = {'f1': range(-3*1850, -3*1910, -3), 
              'f2': range(2401, 2482), 
              'f3': range(5150, 5850)}

sums = {item: [[item]] for item in rangedict3['f1']}
# sums = {-5550: [[-5550]], -5553: [[-5553]], ...}

new_sums = defaultdict(list)
for sm, ways in sums.items():
    for item in rangedict3['f2']:
        new_sum = sm + item
        for way in ways:
           new_sums[new_sum].append(way + [item])
# new_sums = {-3149: [[-5550, 2401], [-5553, 2404], ...],
#             -3148: [[-5550, 2402], [-5553, 2405], ...],
#             ....}         

for item in rangedict3['f3']:
    if possiblesolution - item in new_sums:
        f1_f2 = new_sums[possiblesolution - item]
        print(f1_f2[0][0]//(-3), f1_f2[0][1], item)
        # print(new_sums[possiblesolution - item], item)
        break
```

that way you could also get the remaining solutions easily.

---

or just lump `f2` and `f3` together:

```
f1 = rangedict3['f1']
f2 = rangedict3['f2']
f3 = rangedict3['f3']

# the sums that are reachable from f2 and f3
f2_f3 = range(2401 + 5150, 2482 + 5850)

for item in f1:
    if possiblesolution - item in f2_f3:
        pmi = possiblesolution - item
        x1 = item//(-3)
        for x2 in f2:
            if pmi-x2 in f3:
                x3 = pmi-x2
                break
        print(x1, x2, x3)
        break
```

---

and a last minor speedup: if you really only need one solution, there are just 4 (probably even 3) possible cases for `x2` and `x3`:

```
f1 = rangedict3['f1']
f2 = rangedict3['f2']
f3 = rangedict3['f3']

min_x2 = min(f2)
max_x2 = max(f2)
min_x3 = min(f3)
max_x3 = max(f3)

# the sums that are reachable from f2 and f3
f2_f3 = range(2401 + 5150, 2482 + 5850 - 1)

for item in f1:
    if possiblesolution - item in f2_f3:
        pmi = possiblesolution - item
        x1 = item//(-3)

        if pmi-min_x2 in f3:
            x2 = min_x2
            x3 = pmi-x2
        elif pmi-max_x2 in f3:
            x2 = max_x2
            x3 = pmi-x2
        elif pmi-min_x3 in f2:
            x3 = min_x3
            x2 = pmi-x3
        # elif pmi-max_x3 in f2:
        else:
            x3 = max_x3
            x2 = pmi-x3

        print(x1, x2, x3)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this. However, overall it actually got slower. The number of calls to sum increased. I believe this is due to the range being extended. Before it was 1910 - 1850 = 60 now its -5550 + 5730 = 180.

Comment: Ok the above comment was for the first part you had posted. Will try the second

Comment: @zeetitan Are you doing `range(-3*1850, -3*1910, -3)` or `range(-3*1850, -3*1910)`?

Comment: Ok this is significantly faster, will try out your second approach as well and respond

Answer (score 0):

1. You're redoing the multiplication for every combination. It would be better to do

   ```
   bound_dict =  [['f1', [1850, 1910]], ['f2', [2401, 2482]], ['f3', [5150, 5850]]
   coefficient = [-3, 1, 1]
   rangedict2={bound_dict(i)[0]:range(coefficient[i]*bound_dict(i)[1][0],coefficient[i]*bound_dict(i)[1][0],coefficient[i]) for i in range(len(coefficient))}
   ```
2. You are iterating over all the combinations, which ignores that your constraint removes a degree of freedom. You should remove the range with the largest number of elements, in this case the third one. This will decrease the number of iterations by a factor of 700.

   ```
   for combination in itertools.product(*rangedict2.values()[:-1]):
       currentsolution = sum(combination)
       if  possiblesolution-currentsolution in rangedict2.values()[:-1]:
           solutionfound = True
           dosomething()
           break
   ```
3. You could try doing a list comprehension:

   ```
   [possiblesolution-currentsolution in rangedict2.values()[:-1] for #etc.
   ```
4. If you do more than three numbers, you could try doing nested for-loops rather than using `combination`. The general implementation of this would be something like this:

   ```
   last_value1 = list(rangedict2.values()[0])[0]       
   last_value2 = list(rangedict2.values()[1])[0] 
   current_sum = last_value1+last_value2
   for value1 in rangedict2.values()[0]:
       current_sum = current_sum+value1-last_value1
       for value2 in rangedict2.values()[1]:
           current_sum = current_sum +value2-last_value2
           #check whether this is a solution
           last_value2 = value2
           #more nested for-loops
       last_value1 = value1
   ```

This way, no matter how long `rangedict2` is, each iteration has to perform only two addition operations, rather than `len(rangedict2)-1` operations. In this case, that turns out to be 2 in both cases, but in the general case this could be fewer operations. In this case, since the difference is always the same, you can do:

```
    for value1 in (rangedict2.values()[0])):
        for current_sum in range(value1+2401,value2+2482):
            #check whether this is a solution
```

5. Looking at your actual numbers, you should be able to simplify the number of combinations just by doing some math. For instance, the only sums you're getting from the last two ranges are from 2401+5150 to 2482+5850-2. You don't need to iterate through 81*700 combinations for that; you just need 81+700.